# Range = Codomain for a measurable map?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega , \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest sigma-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains all the open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ (which means $\mathcal{B}$ is a Borel set). Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable map, meaning
$$ X^{-1}(A)= \{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\in A\}\in \mathcal{F},\ \forall A\subseteq \mathcal{B}$$

Then my question is:

(1) Will the codomain of the map $X$ equal to the range of map $X$?

(2) If yes, then why?

Comment: Do you know difference between codomain and range?

Comment: Yes, I know the difference.

Comment: If you take codomain to be $\mathbb R$, then it is quite easy to find measurable function whose range is not the whole $\mathbb R$. For example any constant function is measurable (in any measure space), but its range is a singleton.

Comment: @Esgeriath ; But if we take a constant function as you said, then it will imply that the random variable $X$ would take only one value which is the singleton, right?

Comment: Yes. You could make all sorts of things, for example Bernouli variable would have range $\{0, 1\}$, etc. There are plenty of distributions which can give you different ranges. Normal and Cauchy are the ones in the top of my head that give you whole $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Esgeriath ; what is your opinion  about the set $\Omega$ in the context of my original question? Can $\Omega$ be any kind of set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138966/discussion-between-esgeriath-and-robin-kurtz).